# Global Exception Handler / @Controller Advice on spring boot 3.0 not being applied

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, controller-advice

I have recently migrated my application from spring boot **2.1** to spring boot **3.0**.
But the problem is that now there are endpoints which are not giving the same response when an error happens, instead I get something like this:

```
 {
        "type": "about:blank",
        "title": "Bad Request",
        "status": 400,
        "detail": "Failed to convert 'id' with value: 'territory'",
        "instance": "/webfront/administration/book/territory"
    }
```

I accomplished this by adding a **@ControllerAdvice** class that extends from *ResponseEntityExceptionHandler*.

However I require some other information, the expected one would be like this:

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Failed to convert 'id' with value: 'territory'",
    "instance": "/webfront/administration/book/territory",
    "timestamp": "2023-04-15 12:02:21",
    "code" : 24
}
```

Here is the implementation of my controller advice that should be applied globally (for the example there is only one exception but in reality there are several).

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static ErrorResponse mapToErrorResponse(Exception e, ApplicationError applicationError, String errorMessage, HttpStatus status) {
        return ErrorResponse.builder(e, status, errorMessage)
                .property("code", String.valueOf(applicationError.getCode()))
                .property("timestamp", Instant.now())
                .build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(FileAccessException.class)
    public ErrorResponse fileAccessException(FileAccessException fae) {
        log.error("File access Exception", fae);
        return mapToErrorResponse(fae, fae.getApplicationError(), fae.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
...
}
```

For some reason this handler is not being detected by spring and the exceptions body continue as the first example without my custom data.

I also have another problem regarding my **UrlAuthenticationFailureHandler** before when the user tried to access an unauthorized route the exception was handled now the body is always empty. I tried adding this config entries to my **application.yml** but it didn't make any difference:

```
server:
   error:
     include-message: ALWAYS
     include-stacktrace: ALWAYS
mvc:
   problemdetails:
     enabled: true
```

Comment: did you see the `log.error("File access Exception", fae);` ? (first guess: it is *not* `FileAccessException`!;)

Comment: no, nothing @xerx593

Comment: Your handler method must return ResponseEntity not just ErrorResponse.

Answer (score 0):

> > did you see the `log.error("File access Exception", fae);` ...

> no, nothing @xerx593

Assuming:

- your logging is set-up correct and level >= error
- and `@ControllerAdvice` picked up correctly

..that means:

**It was *no* `FileAccessException`**
(but another one, ..set a breakpoint!)

Look at the [impl of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java#L114-L131), it registers exception handler for "bunch of"/many types of Exceptions and is "the default".

Configured via `ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler`([web](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler.java)|[webflux](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler.java)), but also (via inheritance) with your custom implementation.

To get "the best" out of your "exception handler" (consider application.properties e.g.), follow the tips [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75937888/592355) (it says "reactive", but: potayto-potahto;):

- Keep/bear the `super` Implementation in mind:

  - existing handler *interfaces*
  - utilize *protected* methods
- Extend your "Error" class from `ErrorResponseException`